# Marker as image

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I'm trying to create a world map using JVectorMap, but I would put the marker as image (marker.png) and not the circle as default. Can I do this?

Comment: Check this solution: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201326/drawing-custom-markers-on-a-jvectormap/15361955#15361955

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, this [feature](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/issues/63) is planned for the one of the next releases.

Answer (score 0):

if you want image marker, use a new layer (div over the svg layer in the map), put a new div for each marker, and set the position.

Get reference to the map

```
map = $("#world-map-gdp").vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

and use the function map.latLngToPoint() to locate the point in the new layer.

```
var newMarkerP = map.latLngToPoint(lat,lng);
$('#marker1').css('top',newMarkerP.x);
$('#marker1').css('left',newMarkerP.y);
```

You can relocate the markers if make zoom or drag, use the same function and apply css left, and css top.

May be you can play with the top and left of the new markers, but is a easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is the official example of image based markers - http://jvectormap.com/examples/marker-icons/

Answer (score -1):

In your marker style setup you can use 'image' instead of 'r':

```
        var myMarkerStyle = {
          initial: {
            image: 'files/fkd/marker.png'
          }
        };
```